# Reset of input field only work if alert done before

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, when a backspace with only 1 charatcer in the field or an Escape character is pressed, I want to clear the field and change the name of the button. I know the condition is met because the button does get renamed but the field refuse to get cleared. My input field only gets reset if I uncomment the //alert('bou'). The button does get the new value of "Scan" but the input remains with the value I typed in. I tried it with the .focus() but no success.

This is my first post here and I have tried to meet all your criteria to make  it an acceptable post.

Thanks.

```js
$("#inputBarcode").on("keydown", function(event){
  //alert('bou');
  if((event.which >=32 && event.which <=126) || //alphanumeric char
     (event.which === 14) ||                        //shift in
     (event.which === 15) ||                        //shift out
     (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) ||    //arrow key
     (event.which === 127)){                        //delete
         $("#scanButton").text("Save");
  }else if((event.which === 27) || (event.which === 8 && $(this).val().length === 1)){                 
         $(this).val('');
         $("#scanButton").text("Scan");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label id="labelMaterialBarcode" class="floatLeft">Material barcode 
     <div id="itemBarcode" role="cotg.Barcode">
         <input id="inputBarcode" class="inlineBlock" role="barcode-data" name="itemBarcode" type="text">
         <button id="scanButton" class="small inlineBlock floatRight" role="scan-button" type="button">Scan</button>
     </div>
</label>
```

Comment: First off, great job. Its not often that first time posters put time and effort into attempting to provide a good question. Second, have you tried the `input` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that `keydown` event gets fired before the value of input gets changed.

You can use `keyup` event instead.